# Unregister plugin in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I use a line chart in Chart.js 2.4.0 and I've registered a plugin to enable tooltips to be shown all the time, not only when hovering one data point.

```
enableChartToAlwaysShowTooltips(): void {
    Chart.plugins.register({
        beforeRender: function (chart) {
            if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                // create an array of tooltips
                // we can't use the chart tooltip because there is only one tooltip per chart
                chart.pluginTooltips = [];
                chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
                    if (dataset.data.length === 1) {
                        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function (sector, j) {
                            chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
                                _chart: chart.chart,
                                _chartInstance: chart,
                                _data: chart.data,
                                _options: chart.options.tooltips,
                                _active: [sector]
                            }, chart));
                        });
                    }
                });

                // turn off normal tooltips
                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
            }
        },
        afterDraw: function (chart, easing) {
            if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
                // we don't want the permanent tooltips to animate, so don't do anything till the animation runs atleast once
                if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
                    if (easing !== 1)
                        return;
                    chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
                }

                // turn on tooltips
                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
                Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function (tooltip) {
                    tooltip.initialize();
                    tooltip.update();
                    // we don't actually need this since we are not animating tooltips
                    tooltip.pivot();
                    tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
                });
                chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You see that I register a new plugin, however I want to "unregister" this plugin in a certain situation programmatically, i.e. the functionality provided by this plugin should not happen.

I was searching for any API documentation and for methods like "remove" or "unregister" but that was not helpful.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you have registered has overridden two methods, `beforeRender` and `afterDraw`, both of which will do absolutely nothing if `chart.config.options.showAllTooltips` is `false`. So, to disable the functionality of your plugin, you can manually manipulate your chart object and set `chart.config.options.showAllTooltips` to `false`.

Caveat 1: You will probably have to `update` the chart afterwards, in order to apply the changes.

Caveat 2: You may have to slightly change the code of your plugin, because the current code messes with `chart.options.tooltips.enabled`. You could have an `else` part to your `if`, which would reinstate the value of `chart.options.tooltips.enabled`. Or you could leave the plugin code as is and manually set the desired value of `chart.options.tooltips.enabled`, together with the value of `chart.config.options.showAllTooltips`.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating the chart.js source code, I found a solution to unregister afterDraw callback.

To make the solution simplify, I'll assume you register only afterDraw callback.

First you have to update register part like below.

```
const afterDrawPlugin = {
  id: 'afterDraw',
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    ...your callback code...
  }
};
Chart.plugins.register(afterDrawPlugin);
```

And unregister the plugin in the section you want to remove afterDraw callback.

```
Chart.plugins.unregister([afterDrawPlugin]);
```